# Did Michael Dorn ever refer to his plane as a 'starship'?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, worf, fandom

In two separate articles on Wikipedia, the following claim is made:

> Actor and pilot Michael Dorn owned a T-33.[6] Dorn, who played the character Worf in the TV series Star Trek: The Next Generation and Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, jokingly referred to the aircraft as his 'starship'.
>   <sub>[Lockheed T-33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_T-33)</sub>

> Dorn is also an accomplished pilot who owns and operates a Lockheed T-33 trainer jet, which he jokingly refers to as his "starship".
>   <sub>[Michael Dorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dorn)</sub>

No source is given in either case.

It's also on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Dorn):

> Dorn is an accomplished pilot and owns and operates an old Air Force T-33 trainer jet, one of the first jet aircraft in the US inventory; it is often referred to as his "starship."

Again, there is no source given.

Presumably the reason why he would call it a starship would be because of his work on *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*. But I can't seem to find a source for this.

**Did Michael Dorn ever refer to his plane as a starship?**

Comment: People may be surprised to hear this, but there’s a deleted scene from “Encounter at Farpoint” where Worf refers to the Enterprise as a plane. It was probably to take place right after the point he aims a phaser at the image of Q on the viewscreen.

Comment: The claim in wikipedia has no citation.  I suspect this isn't true.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question, @Tim ...

Comment: Lol. I've asked Michael to confirm or deny it.

Comment: @Valorum oops, so did I! https://twitter.com/SteseDav/status/1072847524422184960

Comment: @Stese - I'm sure he'll appreciate the attention. That being said, definitely a good idea to post a comment so that we don't fall over our own feet.